# I am trying to edit the frontend of dspace getting an error when I try to compile the files required for frontend by the command yarn build:prod

Tags: node.js, linux, bootstrap-4, repository, dspace

```
  $ yarn run bulld:ssr

 $ ng build--configuration production &8 ng run dspace-angular:s node:                 Internal/modules/cjs/loader: 1878 throw err; er:production

A
```

Error: Cannot find module './bootstrap'

```
Require stack: 
at Module._resolveFilename (node: Internal/modules/cjs/loader: 1875:15) 
at Module._load (node: internal/modules/cjs/loader-928:27) 
at Module.require (node: internal/modules/cjs/loader: 1141:19)
at require (node: internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/library/dspace-7.6-Frontend/node_modules/.bin/ng:65:3) 
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader: 1254:14) 
at Module._extensions..js (node: internal/modules/cjs/loader:1388:10)
at Module load (node: internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at Function.executeUser EntryPoint [as runMain] (node: Internal/modules/run_nain:81-12) {              code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND",
```

requireStack: ['/home/library/dspace-7.6-frontend/node_modules/.bin/ng"]

```
Node.js v18.15.0
```

error Command failed with exit code 1.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

```
error Command failed with exit code 1.
I am getting this error
```

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I tried online solutions but it didnt work.
We are creating an institioanal repository for our college
We are getting error when we try to compile frontend

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.